# Efficient way to Populate Table with multidimensional JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I'm looking to the most efficient way to convert this json.

```
{  
   "Kitchen":{  
      "protocol":[  
         "pollin"
      ],
      "id":[  
         {  
            "systemcode":31,
            "unitcode":1
         }
      ],
      "state":"off"
   },
   "BBQ":{  
      "protocol":[  
         "pollin"
      ],
      "id":[  
         {  
            "systemcode":31,
            "unitcode":4
         }
      ],
      "state":"off"
   },
   "Server":{  
      "protocol":[  
         "pollin"
      ],
      "id":[  
         {  
            "systemcode":15,
            "unitcode":1
         }
      ],
      "state":"off"
   }
}
```

Into the following table:

```
[Name]   [Protocol] [Systemcode] [S] [State]
Kitchen   pollin     31           1          off
BBQ       pollin     31           4          off
Server    pollin     15           1          off
```

My page consists of a table in html and jquery is already loaded.

```
<table class="table" id="tableDevices">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Protocol</th>
        <th>Systemcode</th>
        <th>Unitcode</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Now I'm looking for the fastest way to loop trough the JSON, and populate the table with the data. I first flattened the JSON, and then fed it to the table with a loop. However the code I modified to flatten the JSON was painfully slow. This is the my first time working with version control and javascript and I apparently didn't commit my code properly. I'm looking for the most efficient way to fill this table and I'm stuck myself so can someone show my the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: How many rows are you dealing with in the real use case? You'd have to go very far out of your way to make a loop for 12 elements slow. Can you provide the solution you already tried?

Comment: Do you control the source output from server? That structure could be greatly improved. Also always provide what you attempted in code ...regardless of it not working well ...otherwise it makes it appear you want someone to do all the work for you and you will get ignored and down voted

Comment: Excuses about `lost my code` just smells bad here .... seems more like a homework assignment question ....and excuses sound like `the dog ate my homework`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, I wasn't aware that it was considered bad practise to not provide your own solution. @charlietfl I dont have control on the output from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've parsed the JSON and have a variable, `data`, that refers to the parsed result.

Then it's a simple `for-in` loop:

```
var tbody = $("<tbody>");
var key, entry, tr;
for (key in data) {
    entry = data[key];
    tr = $("<tr>");
    $("<td>").text(key).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td>").text(entry.protocol[0]).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td>").text(entry.id[0].systemcode).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td>").text(entry.id[0].unitcode).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td>").text(entry.state).appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo(tbody);
}
tbody.appendTo("#tableDevices");
```

That said, you might look at a templating library like Handlebars instead.

**Live Example:**

```js
// This stands in for the parsed JSON
var data = {
  "Kitchen": {
    "protocol": [
      "pollin"
    ],
    "id": [{
      "systemcode": 31,
      "unitcode": 1
    }],
    "state": "off"
  },
  "BBQ": {
    "protocol": [
      "pollin"
    ],
    "id": [{
      "systemcode": 31,
      "unitcode": 4
    }],
    "state": "off"
  },
  "Server": {
    "protocol": [
      "pollin"
    ],
    "id": [{
      "systemcode": 15,
      "unitcode": 1
    }],
    "state": "off"
  }
};

var tbody = $("<tbody>");
var key, entry, tr;
for (key in data) {
  entry = data[key];
  tr = $("<tr>");
  $("<td>").text(key).appendTo(tr);
  $("<td>").text(entry.protocol[0]).appendTo(tr);
  $("<td>").text(entry.id[0].systemcode).appendTo(tr);
  $("<td>").text(entry.id[0].unitcode).appendTo(tr);
  $("<td>").text(entry.state).appendTo(tr);
  tr.appendTo(tbody);
}
tbody.appendTo("#tableDevices");
```

```html
<table class="table" id="tableDevices">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Protocol</th>
      <th>Systemcode</th>
      <th>Unitcode</th>
      <th>State</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note that the JSON structure is fairly odd. You have arrays lying around that have just one entry in them.

Comment: @gibberish: No need for fiddles, there's a Stack Snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Datables](https://www.datatables.net/) instead? You will have most of the burden of populating the table lifted from your shoulders.